# importing objects from json file into angular adds "default" object wrapper

Tags: json, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to set up some tests in angular.  In order to make this easier I created some default json objects in separate json files that can be imported and used in the test.

see below for simple test

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SignServicesCostService } from '../signServices.costs.service';
import { ServiceType, ClientDetail } from 'app/shared/entities';
import { BranchZone } from 'app/shared/entities/branchZone';
import * as bZones from './BranchZones.json';
import * as sTypes from './ServiceTypes.json';
import * as dClient from './ClientDemo.json';

describe('SignCostsService', () => {
  let service: SignServicesCostService;
  const demoCLient: ClientDetail = dClient;
  const services: ServiceType[] = sTypes;
  const branches: BranchZone[] = bZones;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [SignServicesCostService],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(SignServicesCostService);
  });
  
  it('COST - RES - 1 Sign - 1 Lister - FIX - Zone 1', () => {
    const fixService = services[15];
    const zone = branches[0];

    const costs = service.calculateResidentialCosts(
      1,
      1,
      demoCLient,
      null,
      null,
      fixService,
      zone
    );
    expect(fixService.Code.toLowerCase()).toEqual('fix');
    expect(costs.Price).toEqual(13);
    expect(costs.Total).toEqual(13);
  });
});
```

Here is an example of the json file for ServiceTypes:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    ... // other props removed for brevity
    "BranchName": ""
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    ...
    "LinkedServiceType": null
  }
]
```

### THE PROBLEM

**EXPECTED:**

I expect that I should just be able to access the item in the object array with `services[15]` like any other array.  But that is not the case

**ACTUAL:**
the import process from the .json file is adding a top level object called **"default"** so I would have to access the items as follows: `services.default[15]`.  This does not work because that type is not seen during compilation, only when actually running the code.
see image here to show you what I mean (I circled the default object that contains the actual array of objects):
[image: debug console for jasmine test]

**WORK AROUND**
in order to get this to work I had to change to following:

```
const fixService = services[15];
const zone = branches[0];
```

to

```
const fixService = services['default'][15];
const zone = branches['default'][0];
```

### QUESTION:

Can someone help me know why this ***default*** is getting added and how to stop it.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON files are provided by your loader as synthetic modules with a single `default` export containing their parsed JSON as a JavaScript object. Therefore using the namespace import syntax, `import * as m from "m.json"`, is unnecessary and the cause of the poor ergonomics you are experiencing. Simply fix your imports: `import m from "m.json"`.

In your specific case

```
import bZones from './BranchZones.json';
import sTypes from './ServiceTypes.json';
import dClient from './ClientDemo.json';
```

Please note that the `--esModuleInterop` / `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and the `--resolveJsonModule` options should specified in your TypeScript configuration depending on your loader and environment.

Comment: thanks!  that worked.  For others who find this I had to add the following flags to my tsconfig file 
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

Comment: Ah yes thank you for pointing that out. You may also want to set `"esModuleInterop": true`. I assumed these flags were already on based on the behavior you described in your question.

Comment: yeah, they were but i just wanted to help others get the full details if they need. thanks again

Comment: "JSON files are provided by your loader" Who's doing this? Webpack?

Comment: @SteveBrush the point is that, given that the op was working on a standard angular project, he has access to a loader which allows importing JSON files as modules. Not all loaders provide this, but most do including Webpack, SystemJS, and Node.js's loader.